# Pyobjc how to access an objective-c method with underscore prefix

Tags: python, objective-c, pyobjc

Im trying to access the following Objective-C method via Pyobjc

```
[foo _bar]
```

Unfortunately, this seems to pose a problem for Pyobjc, since the underscores are usually replaced by colons, so if I use the following in PyObjc

```
foo._bar_()
```

I get an error that the object foo does not have a method, i.e.:

```
Attribute Error: No Selector :bar:
```

So how can the prefix underscore be properly "escaped"?

Comment: The correct method call on the Python side would be `foo._bar()`, but other than that, this should not be happening: `>>> import objc
>>> objc.__version__
'2.3.2a0' >>> from Cocoa import *
>>> a = NSArray.array()
>>> a._scriptingExists()
0` Leading underscore handling was fixed _many_ years ago. What version of PyObjC are you using?

Comment: I'm using the same version...very bizarre.

Comment: As Josh mentioned the right way to call is 'foo._bar()' (no underscore at the end of the method). The name in the  AttributeError is an attribute error, because '_foo:' doesn't exist the bridge tries to find other variants of the name and uses the last attempt in the exception message.